# changing rgraph color without resetting the graph

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, rgraph

I try to set a diffrent graph color depending on a user given threshold. The examples given recommend you to reset the graph using `RGraph.Reset(graph1);` and then redrawing the graph entirely:

```
            graph[graph1]  = new RGraph.VProgress({
            id: graph1,
            min: 0, 
            max: 40,
            value: celsius[graph1],
            options: {scale: {decimals: 1},
            gutter: {left:  2, right: 40, bottom: 10},
            labels: {position: "right", count: 5},
            colors:['#FF0000']}
            }).draw
```

While this works as expected (graph is now in new color), the redraw animation starts from graphs bottom all the way up to the new value. Because of the way the application works (think of it as a thermometer) the graph keeps redrawing what results in a nasty looking animation.

I tried `graph[graph1].colors ='#5A8F29';` with no success. 
Is there a way to manipiluate the graphs color without resetting  it or a way to animate it more elegant?

[Link to screenshot](http://i.pictr.com/p8772id4xi.png)
    [Link to Gif](http://i.pictr.com/oj9dbmx7ui.gif) (the recording messed with the color, important is the change form green to red / blue to red)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The support helped me out:

```
graph[graph1].set('colors', ['#FF0000']);
RGraph.redraw();
```

This did the trick. No resetting is needed here.